# What is the term for marks in geometric picture that show congruence?

Tags: geometry, terminology

When looking at a given picture to be used in a geometric proof, often times single, double, or triple "slashes" mark off equal line segments or arcs. What is the correct term for these? I've seen hatch marks, hash marks, tick marks, tic marks, slash marks, etc. Wikipedia uses the term hatch marks [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hatch_mark#Congruency_notation), but I'd rather not just take their word for it.

Comment: Cross posted at https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/q/12392/1248. Please [do not do that](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/71949/188688).

Comment: I will tailor better to each audience in the future. I would like both the mathematician's perspective, and the educators's perspective.